# Issues with Raspbian installation

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, raspi-config

I've been trying to setup my raspberry pi and preconfigure the SD card for wifi before plugging it into my pi. I started using the instructions [here](http://blog.self.li/post/63281257339/raspberry-pi-part-1-basic-setup-without-cables). Originally, my pi was already preconfigured for XBox Media Center when I bought it, but I wiped the SD card (SanDisk) when I followed these [instructions](https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/getting-started-raspberry-pi-install-raspbian). In the first article, the author says that once Raspbian is installed on my SD card, I should be able to use 'sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces' to access the interfaces file and begin configuring the Pi for wifi. However, when I try this command, Nano clearly indicates that this is a new file in a new directory, so it did not exist after the Raspbian installation. I changed directories into the disk (/Volumes/boot/) and do not see the etc directory anywhere. Instead I have:

```
bootcode.bin
cmdline.txt
config.txt
fixup_cd.dat
fixup_x.dat
issue.txt
kernel.img
LICENSE.oracle
start_cd.elf
start_x.elf
start.elf
```

I cd'd into bootcode.bin, but did not find the etc folder. I've tried searching for what contents should be in the SD card after I complete the installation, but every guide just shows what the output should look like after running the dd command, then says 'plug in the pi and boot it'. I don't have a monitor, keyboard or mouse available to do this so I have to run a headless setup. Can someone please explain if I've installed this incorrectly?

Comment: What OS are you doing this on?

Comment: "before plugging it into my pi"--the raspbian install doesn't complete until you boot it in your pi.   You need to hook a keyboard and monitor initially even if you plan to run it headless later.  Some of the configuration simply has to be done live.

Comment: Tyson, thanks for the info. I had a feeling...

@Milliways, this is on OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX does not support `Ext4` so you won't be able to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` on the Pi.

'sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces' would be trying to access the file on your Mac.

You will need a Linux machine if you want to do this, but it will be easier just to boot the Pi.

Comment: What about a Linux virtual machine? I have a couple of Ubuntu machines.

Comment: Actually, I think I can figure something out here. I've found a few articles. I'll post back in comments once I've tried it out. Thanks!

Comment: You could use a virtual machine. You have to make sure it has access to the SD Card. I have done this with hard discs, but not SD. You could always boot to a Linux disk.